# How do I check compatibility of MCUs? I want to connect an ESP32 and an MSP430 together

Tags: microcontroller, esp32, msp430

I want to connect an MSP430FR6989 and ESP32 together in order to give the MSP430 WiFi functionality for a project I am working on. I am still new to working with MCUs so I was wondering if it is possible to connect the two, and how would one know in general if two MCUs can be connected together?

Comment: any two MCUs can be connected together

Comment: What @jsotola said -- _why_ do you want to connect them together?  What do you want to get out of it?  Since the ESP32 is a much more capable processor, what do you want from the MSP430 that the ESP32 can't give you?

Comment: Since presumably you want these two microcontrollers to _talk_ to each other, please _edit your question_ with details of what sorts of information you want to pass between them, and how rapidly.  Giving us a general description of the problem you want to solve with the pair of microcontrollers is probably a very good start.

Comment: You can probably connect them using serial port, or maybe SPI bus or maybe I2C bus. If one of those will work for your intended application, then you may be in business. You cannot connect them in a more intimate way such that they have access to each others memory buses and so-on.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer : you can connect any pair of MCUs together (in some cases you might need some extra circuit to do the interface, for example a level shifter).

Long answer :
If you want to easily communicate between 2 micro-controllers, then I would recommend :

1. to ensure they are using the same voltage (for I/O, ie input and outputs) : this is not a strong requirement (you can easily add a level shifter if you have to work with 2 different voltages), but it makes your life easier
2. check that both support a same protocol, and that you can spare the corresponding pins on both MCUs   (nb : if need be, you can implement custom protocols using GPIOs (ie general purpose input/output pins), but it is complicated an inefficient)
3. ideally, choose a simple and well suited protocol. If you begin, I would go for simple serial (ie TX/RX pins, sometime called UART) if you want each MCU to send data to the other one whenever it wants, or I2C if you want a master and a slave. If you start to have more specific needs, there are plenty of other protocols (SPI, USB, CAN, ...)

And finally, and most important of all : use what you already know : it is easier to use a protocol you know, and it is easier to use a level shifter than to learn to use a new board to get the same voltages